# Spring Session: How to create separate session management policies for different URLs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

In spring boot project using spring session, how can we configure two session management policies for different URLs?

1. For Angular frontend, I would like to use the default implementation and create `X-Auth-Token` token(creates session if required)
2. But for exposed API endpoints I would like to use Stateless session management

I tried the following config, but session is not being created at all. I think second block is overwriting the `sessionCreationPolicy` since it is at the end

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {


//Requests from angular app
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login","/api/v1/user/login", "/api/v1/user/authenticate", "/api/v1/user/logout", "/api/v1/health/find/status").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/person/**").hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_USER)
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
        .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

//Requests from external systems
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/external/**").hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_API_USER)
        .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

}
```

**Update**

Added Custom WebSecurity Configurer Adapters for API endpoints and Angular app as shown below. After adding this, API endpoint does not create session but Angular HTTP request also not creating session

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
 ....

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class ExternalApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        {
            auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).eraseCredentials(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/search/**").hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_API_USER, ROLE_SYS_ADMIN)
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.headers()
                    .frameOptions().disable();

            // Uses CorsConfigurationSource bean defined below
            http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class DefaultSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
        {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity)
        {
            webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login","/api/v1/user/login", "/api/v1/user/authenticate", "/api/v1/user/logout", "/api/v1/health/find/status").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/person/**").hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_USER)
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
        .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        {
            auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).eraseCredentials(true);
            auth.authenticationProvider(getDaoAuthenticationProvider()).eraseCredentials(true);
        }

    }
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two different filter chains, when you create a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you are creating a proxy filter chain that contains the required security http filters.

You should be able to see this on start up if you look for `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` in the logs, you again should see a logging statement along the lines of `Creating filter chain: any request, [Filters...]`

The `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` by default is any request  (`/**`) will go through it. To be able to separate out requests to different filter chains you need to create a second `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, scope it to whatever paths and apply configuration you want to each one.

One gotcha is that you also need to apply a higher order of precedence to the adapter, the end code would look something like.

```
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
    @Configuration
    public static class ApiSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/v1/external/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_API_USER)
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
    }

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 2)
    @Configuration
    public static class DefaultSecurityFilter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //Requests from angular app
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login","/api/v1/user/login", "/api/v1/user/authenticate", "/api/v1/user/logout", "/api/v1/health/find/status").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/person/**").hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_USER)
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                    .and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
        }
    }
```

after this you should see two `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` being created in the logs, the first being `"/api/v1/external/**"` and the second `any request` to catch any other request.

Comment: @Jadda make sure to  scope one of the filters. Looking at your update only one of those filters will ever be hit. In my `apiFilter` you can see this line `http.antMatcher("/api/v1/external/**")` that will scope the entire filter to only trigger on this path.